# Do I need to create all nodes by hand in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am probably missing something because I am very new to Neo4j, but looking at their Movie graph - probably the very first graph to play with when you are learning the platform - they give us a really big piece of code where every node and labels and properties are imputed by hand, one after the other. Ok, it seems fair to a small graph for learning purpose. But, how should I proceed when I want to import a CSV and create a graph from this data? I believe a hand-imput is not expected at all.

My data look something like this:

| date | origin | destiny | value | type | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-05-2021 | A | B | 500 | transf | 2500 |

It has more than 10 thousand rows like this.
I loaded it as:

`LOAD CSV FROM "file:///MyData.csv" AS data`

`RETURN data;`

and it worked. The data was loaded etc. But now I have some questions:

1- How do I proceeed if I want `origin` to be a node and `destiny` to be another node with `type` to be edges with `value` as property? I mean, I know how to create it like `(a)->[]->(b)` but how to create the entire graph without creating edge by edge, node by node, property by property etc...?

2- Am I able to select the `date` and see something like a time evolution for this graph? I want to see all transactions in 20-05-2021, 01-05-2021 etc and see how it evolves. Is it possible?

Comment: loading data into neo4j needs a script to load edge by edge, node by node and property by property. there is no shortcut. Can you give us example of what you are asking in question#1?  for question#2, you can create a graph of time series based on dates to see how your data is evolving for each date

Comment: Question 1 is more straightforward: I want the graph! I want to see all connections between accounts (the origin and destiny columns). There will be a lot. But for n rows I only know how to use `CREATE` n times but for large n this will be impossible or would take me an entire month hhehehe so, how can this script be? I never saw an example, a good reference would be cool.

As for question 2, a good reference would be awesome. I do not know how to create a graph of time series. I am really new to neo4j and graph databases. Still learning the basics

Comment: for question#1, you mean you want all nodes to be connected to each other, meaning a complete graph? that would be n*(n-1)/2 combinations. it is doable by using a FOREACH statement.

Comment: No, it does not have to be a complete graph. My problem is how to create the graph at first place. In other words: after importing the csv how do I tell neo4j which cell is a node and which node connects to another node and how is this connection.

Is it possible to create a function that does this?

I mean, with 10 thousand lines it is not possible to write 10 thousand CREATE clauses, right? There must be a 'for' loop to run though each line and give me a  graph at the end. Does neo4j supports this or they think I'm crazy?

Answer (score 1):

As example in the official docs says here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/neo4j-admin-import/#tutorial-neo4j-admin-import

You may want to create 3 separate files for the import:

**First: you need the movies.csv to import nodes with label :Movie**

```
movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL
tt0133093,"The Matrix",1999,Movie
tt0234215,"The Matrix Reloaded",2003,Movie;Sequel
tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie;Sequel
```

**Second: you need actors.csv to import nodes with label :Actor**

```
personId:ID,name,:LABEL
keanu,"Keanu Reeves",Actor
laurence,"Laurence Fishburne",Actor
carrieanne,"Carrie-Anne Moss",Actor
```

**Finally, you can import relationships**

As you see, actors and movies are already imported. So now you just need to specify the relationships. In the example, you're importing ROLE relationship in the given format:

```
:START_ID,role,:END_ID,:TYPE
keanu,"Neo",tt0133093,ACTED_IN
keanu,"Neo",tt0234215,ACTED_IN
keanu,"Neo",tt0242653,ACTED_IN
laurence,"Morpheus",tt0133093,ACTED_IN
laurence,"Morpheus",tt0234215,ACTED_IN
laurence,"Morpheus",tt0242653,ACTED_IN
carrieanne,"Trinity",tt0133093,ACTED_IN
carrieanne,"Trinity",tt0234215,ACTED_IN
carrieanne,"Trinity",tt0242653,ACTED_IN
```

So as you see in the header, you've got values:
START_ID - where the relationship starts, from which node
role - property name (you can specify multiple properties here, just make sure the csv format contains data for it)
:END_IN - where the relationship ends, to which node
:TYPE - type of the relationship

That's all :)